# Excel, analisar condição na tabela de dados

Tags: microsoft-excel, condição

Preciso alterar uma coluna de valores em excel de acordo com a condição de outra coluna. Por exemplo, analisar classificações fiscais e se forem de "devoluções de venda" preciso alterar a quantidade para negativa. Como fazer?

Comment: Seja bem-vinda.  Por favor, leia o [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/75104), [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas) e [Seja mais específico na pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1481/75104)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como havia dito, apesar da boa solução com função dada pelo @LeandroLuk, resolvi fazer codigo para um botão, que posto abaixo. Neste código altero diretamente o campo "quantidade" e valores de impostos para NFs de "devolução", as vendas permanecem com valores positivos (sempre analiso toda a tabela para que eu possa inserir novas linhas):

```
Private Sub bDEVOL_Click()

Dim DEV As Worksheet
Set DEV = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DEVOLUCOES")

Dim vlQTD As String, vlTOT As String, vlICM As String, vlPIS As String, vlCOFINS As String, vlIPI As String
Dim Lin As Variant, UltLin As Long

With DEV
    UltLin = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For Lin = 3 To UltLin
        vlQTD = .Cells(Lin, "G").Value 'quantidade
        vlTOT = .Cells(Lin, "H").Value 'Vlr total da NF
        vlIPI = .Cells(Lin, "J").Value 'Vlr IPI
        vlICM = .Cells(Lin, "K").Value 'Vlr ICM
        vlPIS = .Cells(Lin, "O").Value 'Vlr PIS
        vlCOFINS = .Cells(Lin, "M").Value 'Vlr COFINS
        If InStr("1201,1202,1410,1411,2201,2410,2411,3201", .Cells(Lin, "Q").Value) > 0 Then 'Class. Fiscais de devolução
            If .Cells(Lin, "G").Value > 0 Then 'se já estiver negativo, ignora para não tornar positivo
                .Cells(Lin, "G").Value = vlQTD * -1
                .Cells(Lin, "H").Value = vlTOT * -1
                .Cells(Lin, "J").Value = vlIPI * -1
                .Cells(Lin, "K").Value = vlICM * -1
                .Cells(Lin, "O").Value = vlPIS * -1
                .Cells(Lin, "M").Value = vlCOFINS * -1
            End If
        End If
    Next Lin
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Que bom que conseguiu a resposta, que vire uma usuária ativa! Pode aceitar a sua resposta como resposta, se possuir dúvidas em como fazer: [leia este post no meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta).

Answer (score 1):

Bom teoricamente, você teria uma coluna com valores do tipo seletivos (valores únicos dentro de uma lista) e a partir destes valores você deveria fazer um tratamento certo? creio então que você deveria ter a seguinte solução:

#### Valores únicos para exemplo:

- **1** [Fica positivo]
- **2** [Fica negativo]
- **3** [ignora e zera o valor]

#### Tabela de exemplo

```
  |    A    | B | C |
  | ------- |---|---|
1 | 100.00  | 1 | ? |
2 | 200.50  | 3 | ? |
3 | 123.45  | 2 | ? |
```

Para que eu satisfaça a coluna "C", usando a regra listada acima, em cada célula da coluna C eu teria algo desse tipo:

```
=SE(B1=1;+A1;SE(B1=2;-A1;SE(B1=3;0;A1)))
```

Essa função faz a validação condicional dos dados na seguinte estrutura:

```
if(B1 == 1) {
    return +A1; /* o valor inicial como positivo */
} else {
    if(B1 == 2) {
        return +A1; /* o valor inicial como negativo */            
    } else {
        if(B1 == 3) { 
            return 0; /* ignora os valores e define um especifico*/
        } else {
            return A1; /* caso nao atenda nada, retorne o valor inicial*/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá @LeandroLuk. Entendi. Acabei fazendo código VBA acionado por um combobox, pois queria alterar o resultado diretamente na coluna a ser analisada. Como levei um "puxãozinho de orelhas", percebi que não formulei direito a pergunta. Vou aprender! Sou nova por aqui! 
Mais tarde, se houver interesse, posto o código. Não me está acessível neste momento.

Comment: Esquenta não @AnaFerri, `=D` só não pode é deixar de ajudar o próximo! Não esquece de definir que foi finalizada sua solução

Comment: falei combobox, mas o correto é botão!